# Create a custom folder and assign user permission

Tags: docker, dockerfile, nextcloud

I'm trying to customize a Dockerfile, I just want to create a folder and assign the user (PID and GID) on the new folder.

Here is my full Dockerfile :

```
FROM linuxserver/nextcloud

COPY script /home/
RUN /home/script
```

The content of the script file :

```
#!/bin/sh
mkdir -p /data/local_data
chown -R abc:abc /data/local_data
```

I gave him the following permission : `chmod +x script`

At this moment it doesn't create the folder, and I see no error in logs.

Command to run the container :

```
docker run -d \
  --name=nextcloud \
  -e PUID=1000 \
  -e PGID=1000 \
  -e TZ=Europe/Paris \
  -p 443:443 \
  -p 8080:80 \
  -v /home/foouser/nextcloud:/config \
  -v /home/foouser/data:/data \
  --restart unless-stopped \
  nextcloud_custom
```

Logs from build :

```
Step 1/3 : FROM linuxserver/nextcloud
 ---> d1af592649f2
Step 2/3 : COPY script /home/
 ---> 0b005872bd3b
Step 3/3 : RUN /home/script
 ---> Running in 9fbd3f9654df
Removing intermediate container 9fbd3f9654df
 ---> 91cc65981944
Successfully built 91cc65981944
Successfully tagged nextcloud_custom:latest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to run the commands directly:

```
RUN mkdir -p /data/local_data && chown -R abc:abc /data/local_data
```

you may try also to chabge your shebang to:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

to debugging you may try to `set -x`in your script a well.

**EDIT:**

I had notice this `Removing intermediate container` in your logs , the solution to it would be to use volume with your `docker run` command:

```
-v /path/your/new/folder/HOST:/path/your/new/folder/container
```

Comment: I tried to run the commands directly and I got the same result

Comment: is it a multi stage Dockerfile? could you please post your Dockerfile ?

Comment: Here is the source of the image https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-nextcloud I'm using the base image. I also added the debug mod in the script and it output no error. The Dockerfile in my question is my full code

Comment: This does not solve the original problem which is a volume handling issue, though the workaround your propose does provide result

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to modify a folder which is specified as a `VOLUME` in your base image, but as per [Docker documentation on Volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#notes-about-specifying-volumes):

> Changing the volume from within the Dockerfile: If any build steps
>   change the data within the volume **after it has been declared**, those
>   changes will be discarded.

[`linuxserver/nextcloud`](https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-nextcloud/blob/master/Dockerfile) does declare a volume `/data` which you are trying to change afterward, it's like doing:

```
VOLUME /data
...
RUN mkdir -p /data/local_data
```

The directory created will be discarded. You can however create your directory **on container startup** by modifying it's entrypoint so when container starts the directory is created. Currently [`linuxserver/nextcloud`](https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-nextcloud/blob/master/Dockerfile) uses `/init` as entrypoint, so you can do:

Your script content which you then define as entrypoint:

```
#!/bin/sh
mkdir -p /data/local_data
chown -R abc:abc /data/local_data

# Call the base image entrypoint with parameters
/init "$@"
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM linuxserver/nextcloud

# Copy the script and call it at entrypoint instead
COPY script /home/
ENTRYPOINT ["/home/script"]
```

Comment: I had this solution in my head but I need to map the volume from my host to local_data

Comment: LinSel solution is what you are looking for then :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have some problem with my app now. I can't delete folders

Comment: You can create another question if you wish, you can tag me in the comment I'll be happy to help

Comment: Thanks for the support @Pierre I'll try to figure it out if I can resolve it first :)

Comment: Here is my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56933876/using-external-storage-getting-error-while-deleting-a-folder thanks for any help