# Using external storage, getting error while deleting a folder

Tags: docker, storage, nextcloud

I'm using docker nextcloud. I created a clean instance and I want to use the application external storage. I managed to configure successfully a local storage using the following command :

```
mount_id=$(docker exec --user 1000 nextcloud php occ files_external:create Home local null::null -c datadir=/var/www/data --output=json)
docker exec --user 1000 nextcloud php occ files_external:applicable --add-user=foo "$mount_id"
```

I can create/move/copy folder and files but when I want to delete  a created folder I got the following error :

> Error deleting file "folderfoo".

It's says it's a file but actually it was a folder. After refreshing the browser the folder is deleted. By the way I can successfully delete files.
I'm using this image https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/nextcloud
I added the right user permission on the docker container and the data folder.

The folder data is under the right user (1000).

I also configured a redis container and linked it to my nextcloud container with `-e REDIS_HOST="redis"` and it give me the following in `config.php` :

```
'memcache.distributed' => '\\OC\\Memcache\\Redis',
'memcache.locking' => '\\OC\\Memcache\\Redis',
'redis' =>
 array (
        'host' => 'redis',
        'port' => 6379,
    ),
```

Here is my command line to create a container :

```
docker run -d \
  --name=nextcloud \
  -e PUID=1000 \
  -e PGID=1000 \
  -e TZ=Europe/Paris \
  -p 443:443 \
  -p 8080:80 \
  -v /home/foo/nextcloud:/config \
  -v /home/foo/data:/local_data \
  --restart unless-stopped \
  linuxserver/nextcloud
```

I always get this issue on the mounted volume. It works on the /data directory but I don't want to point on this directory because it's all nextcloud data.

I also tried with the official docker nextcloud, I get the same issue.
I don't know what I'm supposed to do, thanks for any help.

**EDIT:**

My issue can be found here https://github.com/nextcloud/server/issues/16306

Comment: Thanks for tagging me, can't help on this one sorry

Comment: did you see this: https://github.com/nextcloud/docker/issues/786 ? it is still open

Comment: @LinPy yep, it's my original post :)

Comment: what happened if you cahnge the permission on your local folder to `766` ?

Comment: I tried and unfortunately it's the same issue